# Packaging list to be deployed at client

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-listtemplate

I have developed a custom list on our sharepoint 2007 site.

I have finished a webpart that will be using this list.  I need to be able to package the list as a template, with the specified columns and views with NO data.  I am going to deploy a SSIS package that will be updating the list based on some files, so no preset data is necessary.

How do i export my dev-list as a model for the clients production-list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List Settings > Save list as template > Uncheck "Include Content"

Comment: once i get the stp, or whatever the extension is, will the client be able to import the structure?

Comment: Yes - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/copying-or-moving-sharepoint-lists-HA001154562.aspx

Comment: Thank you, that was a major concern based on the "light reading" i did on the export feature.  I love how they reference a organizations internal structure and never give a "note" for developers.  I rarely develop on their structure and have to build small-scale mock-up and would love it if their documentation was more clear on first glance about transportability.